# Why got rejected on posting open graph message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, review

I have an iOS app with integration of Facebook. This app used facebook open graph and post some activity message when the player does something important in the game. The open graph message are tagged as explicit_shared. But I got rejected after reviewed by facebook and the reasons are as below:

*Posting Explicitly Shared content must be optional. In the Open Graph action flow, users need to know that they are sharing content back to Facebook and have the ability to opt-out.*

I know what it means. But the point is, the app didn't automatically post the open graph message. Only when the player click a specific button, the message will be sent. For example, there is a button like "share my score on facebook", and when the player clicks on it, the app will post an open graph message. So I think what I did confirms to the guideline. I don't understand why it's rejected in this case.

Comment: Are you setting the explicitly shared parameter on an action where you're posting it without the user actually typing in a message and confirming it? If so, that's probably it

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts from the docs:

*It represents something they would have entered or uploaded into the Facebook composer for sharing.*

Even though in your app the users are clicking the share button, it does not count as explicit sharing because users are not providing with any status message when they are sharing.

[More Reading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#explicitsharing)

Hope this helps.